# Swift: UIImageView position does not update when DispatchQueue is used

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, grand-central-dispatch, uipangesturerecognizer

Based on the upcoming code:

`myButtonAction` runs a time consuming task that I send to the background. I have a pan gesture that handles interaction for another set of actions. the line of `transChange.center = hitPoint` in `handleChangedPanGesture` works as expected, dragging the element and setting it to my point position but when the `myButtonAction` is activated and the user continues to interact with the pan gesture, the position of `transChange` does not update on screen even though its value does get updated by `hitPoint`, it simply defaults back to "center X" "center Y" (static position) as defined in AutoLayout. Interestingly though, the rotate extension does continue to function. As soon as `DispatchQueue.global().async` ends the pan function again works as expected.

```
@IBAction func myButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        ...
            myButton.isEnabled = false
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                self.addBlock(block) // This is a loop I send to the background
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.myButton.isEnabled = true
                }
            }
    }

@objc func handlePanGesture(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        let point = gesture.location(in: gesture.view!)
        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            handleBeganPanGesture(point)
        case .changed:
            handleChangedPanGesture(point)
        case .ended:
            handleEndPanGesture(point)
        default: break
        }
    }

func handleChangedPanGesture(_ hitPoint: CGPoint) {

        let myAngle = 2 * (hitPoint.x - panStartPoint.x)
        transChange.rotate(degrees: myAngle)
        transChange.center = hitPoint

        ...
    }
```

EDIT: Note I removed the AutoLayout constraints and the general issue persists. The UIImageView now anchors to the top left. Again, it does update its position normally using the pan gesture but only when the DispatchQueue is not running the background function. How can I force a layout update while the Dispatch is running? Here are two image that show both scenarios
[image]
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Isn't that the samo-samo Autolayout thing that pops up here every month?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to? I've seen a lot of responses about this translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints but that doesn't fix my issue. Code works as expected, except when DispatchQueue action is triggered. it may be an autolayout issue but I'm not sure what is perhaps someone could point me in the right direction. Thank you!